# C# Serial Communication DLL

Tags: c#, dll, serial-port

I'm developing in a DLL a serial communication protocol. I have a class for this matter, in there I have separated in different methods:

1. Open serial communication.
2. Write and read data (to a PLC).
3. Close serial communication.

From the project that uses the DLL I can open and close serial communication, but when I use write, the event handler never activates. I don't understand why. I tried to develop the code to test serial communication in a separeted project (without the DLL), it works fine and I can communicate with the PLC. So I thought it might be that I have to keep alive the DLL, I used some timers but it didn't work.

Serial class in the DLL:

```
            public class Serial
            {
             SerialPort com = new SerialPort(GlobalData.PLC_ADDRESS, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

              public void Open()
                {
                  // Read event handler
                    com.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(com_DataReceived);

                    // Set the read/write timeouts
                    com.ReadTimeout = 400;
                    com.WriteTimeout = 400;
                    // Open the port for communication.
                    com.Open();
    }

           public void Talk2PLC()
            {
                byte[] cmd = { 17, 3, 0, 64, 0, 100, 71, 101};
                com.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
    }


        public void com_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
 Console.WriteLine($"Inside com_DataReceived");

            // Buffer and process binary data
            while (com.BytesToRead > 0)
                PlcBuffer.Add((byte)com.ReadByte());
}
        public void Close()
        {
                // Close the port
                com.Close();


    }
}
```

From the project that uses the DLL with this methods, I call first Open(), then Talk2PLC.

I used also "IsOpen" in the DLL to check if port is open or not, I didn't copied here to have a clearer code.

What should I do to do that the code enters in "com_DataReceived(...)"? I wrote a  Console.WriteLine(..) to check when it enters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Mitsubishi I didn't find any issue,  can make com.DtrEnable = true before com.Open()